# Simple doubt about matrix inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a square complex matrix and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ a eigenvalue of $A$. So I have
$$Ax = \lambda x,$$
for some $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ eigenvector. Now, I can multiply by $x^{*}$ and the
$$x^*Ax = \lambda x^*x.$$
So, my doubt is this: when I use inner product notation I have
$$\langle x, Ax\rangle\ =\ \langle x, \lambda x\rangle,$$
and then
$$\langle x, Ax\rangle\ =\ \overline{\lambda}\langle x,x\rangle.$$
Am I right? Because I don't know what is my problem of notation, i.e, Is correct to write $x^*Ax = \lambda x^*x$? or is $x^*Ax = \overline{\lambda}x^*x$.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Git Gud, Thanks so much

Comment: Done. Check below the firdt gray box.

Comment: Do you know about duality?

Comment: I am beginning to study that, and then I though in this doubt, Why I am confusing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I can multiply by $x^{*}$ and the
>   $$x^*Ax = \lambda x^*x.$$
>   So, my doubt is this: when I use inner product notation I have
>   $$\langle x, Ax\rangle\ =\ \langle x, \lambda x\rangle,$$

If $\langle x, Ax\rangle =x^*Ax$, then $\lambda x^*x=\langle \overline\lambda x, x\rangle =\overline {\overline \lambda }\langle x, x\rangle=\lambda \langle x, x\rangle$.

> and then
>   $$\langle x, Ax\rangle\ =\ \overline{\lambda}\langle x,x\rangle.$$

This not right. Using your definition of inner product $\langle x,\lambda x\rangle=\lambda \langle x,x\rangle$. You'd be right if your definition was $\langle x,y\rangle =y^*x$.

> Because I don't know what is my problem of notation, i.e, Is correct to write $x^*Ax = \lambda x^*x$? or is $x^*Ax = \overline{\lambda}x^*x$

If $(\lambda ,x)$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then $Ax=\lambda x$ therefore $x^*Ax=x^*(\lambda x)=\lambda x^*x$. Your second option is incorrect.

Comment: Then the correct notation is: $x^*Ax = \overline{\lambda}x^*x$. ?

Comment: @FASCH No, check my last edit.

Comment: I see, but what is the problem here:$$\langle x, Ax\rangle\ =\ \langle x, \lambda x\rangle\ =\ \overline{\lambda}\langle x,x\rangle\ ?$$ Thanks for the time.

Comment: @FASCH The problem is with the first equality. Check the line below the first gray box in my answer. If you still don't understand the problem, please tell me your definition of inner product.

Comment: My definition is: $\langle x, y\rangle = x^*y$. And in the first equality I only used the fact of $Ax = \lambda x$. Thanks

Comment: How do you obtain this equalities: $$\lambda x^*x=\langle \overline\lambda x, x\rangle =\overline {\overline \lambda }=\lambda\ ?$$

Comment: @FASCH I believe I answered your question below the second gray box.

Comment: Yes, you are. Thanks so much!